# Why is Gulp not accessing my AppAPI.js file?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where I am using gulp. However, gulp keeps throwing an error saying it cannot find the AppAPI.js file in my work environment. I am building with Reactjs and Flux. I believe the problem may be in my gulpfile, but after trying various versions of the code, I have not been able to get anywhere. Could someone take a look and see if indeed my code is wrong or if there could be something else going wrong? Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify'); // Converts jsx to js
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Converts string to a stream

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    browserify('./src/js/main.js')
        .transform('reactify')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('copy', function(){
    gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    gulp.src('src/css/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
    gulp.src('src/js/vendors/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'copy'], function(){
    return gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['browserify', 'copy']);
});
```

I am requiring appAPI.js in my main.js file:

```
var App = require('./components/App');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var AppAPI = require('./utils/appAPI.js');


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is the appAPI.js code:

```
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');

module.exports = {

}
```

Comment: This looks more like you are requiring AppAPI.js somewhere in your app, but the reference is incorrect

Comment: Yes, I am requiring it in my main.js. In what way am I referencing it wrong?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: And are you actually exporting something from appApi.js?

Comment: So as far as my folder structure, I have an src folder. My gulpfile.js is not in that folder. What is inside the src folder is my main.js file and some other folders such as: actions, components, constants, dispatcher, stores, utils and vendors. Inside the utils folder is where my appAPI.js file is located. I am not exporting anything from appAPI.js. I am posting the code for that file above. Hope this helps you help me and thank you.

Comment: So you don't have a src/js folder?

Comment: Sorry guys, let me clarify, the folders inside src are: css, js and inside of the js folder are: actions, components, constants, dispatcher, stores, utils and vendors. Inside the utils folder is where my appAPI.js file is located.

Comment: ive replicated your folder structure locally and used the code that you supplied and everything works fine, gulp runs fine so it's not your gulpfile. I would suspect its maybe a typo somewhere in your filename, whats the exact error you are getting from gulp?